# How space of wavelets is created from {0}?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, wavelets

I have learned about wavelets and there is a space $$... V_{-1} \subset V_0 \subset V_1   $$ and they create as a closure of sum of $V_j$ all space $L^2(\Bbb{R})$.
There are some other points, but one is struggling me $\bigcap_{j \in \Bbb{Z}}V_{j}={0}$ which in space of functions is $f(x) = 0$. Then we have two operators $T_k$ (shifting) and $D^j$ (scaling) which are used in construction such that: $$V_{j+1}=D(V_j)$$ and $$f \in V_0 \Rightarrow T_kf \in V_0$$ The questions is how that space is possible if it have to starts from function $f(x) = 0$ which treated by $D$ or $T$ operators stay in zero vector? What I am missing, could you help?

Comment: I would say that this is valid for their orthogonal complemens $\bigcap_{j \in \Bbb{Z}}W_{j}={0}$.

Comment: The process is described on this video: https://youtu.be/lj4EMpK_khg?t=1849 Maybe it will explain better what did I mean.

Comment: Then it must be because infinitelly dilated subspace $V_\infty = \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Yes, and then, the question is, how we can leave that using $T$ and $D$ operators? How is it possible to have $V_{0}$ full of functions?

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain. Does [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiresolution_analysis) help you understanding?